# How to correctly reference a function in an anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, namespaces, language-lawyer

Consider this fragment of C++ code:

```
namespace
{
    void f()
    {
    }

    class A
    {
        void f()
        {
            ::f(); // VC++: error C2039: 'f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
        }
    };
}
```

GCC compiles this just fine.  Visual C++ 2008 fails to compile spitting out the C2039 error.  Which one of these two compilers is correct here?  Is there any way to reference that *"global"* `f` properly?

**Edit:** Zack suggested to try and it works with both compilers.  Looks a bit weird to me.

```
namespace
{
    void f()
    {
    }

    class A
    {
        void f();
    };
}

void A::f()
{
    ::f();
}
```

Comment: Not that I know a real answer, but maybe that also counts: Use function names that don't hide the outer names? :)

Comment: I agree.  This is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: Sure, and I think it's pretty interesting. +1 for finding that.

Comment: What happens if you pull the definition of `A::f` outside `class A`?  What if you pull it all the way out of the anonymous namespace declaration?

Comment: @Zack: That works! Edit: If you pull it all the way out of the anonymous namespace, not if it's still inside but out of the `class A`

Comment: Zack, it works.  But I see possible problems with `::A::f`, if there's one.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that being an issue.  Also, to be clear, I don't know which compiler is *correct*.  I just guessed that MSVC++ might be treating the anonymous namespace members as not `using`-ed into the global namespace until after the anon namespace is closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VC++ 2008 is wrong here.  According to the c++03 standard 3.4.3.4:

> A name prefixed by the unary scope
>   operator :: (5.1) is looked up in
>   global scope, in the translation unit
>   where it is used.  The name shall be
>   declared in global namespace scope or
>   shall  be a name whose declaration is
>   visible in global scope because  of a
>   using-directive (3.4.3.2). The use of
>   :: allows a global  name to be
>   referred to even if its identifier has
>   been hidden  (3.3.7).

The important part here is that a using directive in the global namespace will make those symbols accessible with the scope operator.

And according to 7.3.1.1/1, an anonymous namespace is equivalent to:

```
namespace *unique* { /* empty body */ }
using namespace *unique*;
namespace *unique* { namespace-body }
```

So between these two sections, the standalone function should be accessible in global namespace.

Answer (score 7):

As academicRobot points out, Visual C++ is wrong.  As a workaround, adding an empty unnamed namespace block should resolve the issue (I don't have Visual C++ 2008 to test, but this works in Visual C++ 2010):

```
// empty unnamed namespace to placate compiler
namespace { }

namespace {
    void f() { }
    struct A {
        void f() { ::f(); }
    };
}
```

I've reported the issue to the Visual C++ team.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I just tested it on VS2008 and it works there as well.  I accepted the academicRobot's answer though, since it explains in details the problem.  Your fix makes perfect sense after his answer.